# Determine key event as key input

Tags: javascript, html, events, input, browser

I'm trying to figure out if an event is a key input event or a non key input event.
Is there a way here to find this out this browser and OS across?

Example:

1. `keyCode: 68` -> `D` -> `INPUT_EVENT`
2. `keyCode: 65` -> `A` -> `INPUT_EVENT`
3. `keyCode: 121`-> `F10` -> `NO_INPUT_EVENT`
4. `keyCode: 27`-> `ESC` -> `NO_INPUT_EVENT`

Comment: Euh, I don't completely understand the question. You get the keyCode from the key event, then you know which key it is. I guess you could use like the Ascii and Unicode ranges to determine if it's a key representing a writable character. But could you please explain more about which problem knowing input_event or not input_event will solve? Since I can't immediately think of a situation where knowing that would matter.

Comment: Are special characters like `à` considered input events? The only feasible solution you have is to handle an array holding all the allowed keycodes, so, out of it, whenever a key is not in the array, it can be considered as no_input_event.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no easy way of doing this. One solution would be to check for `event.key` which will return a string value as described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values
You could blacklist these values or whitelist the input keys (i.e. alphanumeric, punctuation, etc). Whatever approach you take, it will be a bit messy.

Alternatively, if you're listening on an input element's keystrokes, you could compare the input's previous value to the latest one. If the value's length has changed, then an input key was pressed. If not, then a non-input one was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a native way to check for that, but here are some options you may explore.

1) use a RegX to check the event key (i.e event.key) is a letter between a to z

2) check if the event.code start with the Key letter

Example

Assuming i have an HTML element like this:

```
<input type="text" id="mytxt">
```

and JavaScript:

```
const ele = document.getElementById('mytxt');
ele.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
if(event.code.startsWith('Key')){
    // valid key
    console.log('valid', event);
}
});
```

This should help you get what you need.